# How to post image with content in Yammer through share button

Tags: yammer

I have need to know how to post content with image and site url to Yammer.
I am using Yammer share button  and used below code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('modyammer-share-cust')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {

  yam.platform.yammerShareOpenPopup({

    defaultMessage:StateName,

    pageUrl: '<?php  echo $post_url; ?>',

    is_rich_text:true,

  });

});
```

I'd like to know:

1. How to post image with content
2. why it's rendering html content as it is, not evaluating html code

Comment: Hi there. Please use the preview window before submitting new edits - if it does not look well-formatted, don't submit it. @il_raffa repaired the code formatting, and your next edit broke that presentation. It may be worth taking ten minutes to practice with Markdown - just use the "Ask Question" button without submitting it. The most important formatting tool is the code block, which can be accessed in the editor toolbar.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Ok.Thank you for your suggestions.Here after will make sure of above points.